# ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator not working with DropDownList Firefox 6

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having an issue validating a dropdownlist with a requiredfieldvalidator in Firefox 6. The code I have works in all browsers, except Firefox 6.

Here is what happens, I select a value from the dropdownlist that is not the default value and click the button. An error message is returned, meaning validation failed even though I have selected a different field. If I do this again, and select the SAME value from the dropdownlist and click the button. No error message, it passes validation. This only fails the first time you select a value, and only in Firefox 6.

Another example, load up the page, select a value, select the same value again, click the button, and it passes. WTH?

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlHour" cssclass="select select-small" runat="server">
  <asp:listitem value="" text="" selected="true"></asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="1">1</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="2">2</asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvHour" initialvalue="" controltovalidate="ddlHour" errormessage="Please select an hour" display="none" validationgroup="banquetForm" runat="server"/>
```

And I have a button with the same validation group later on in the form. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: I noticed that you have `Display` set to `none`. Are you changing that to `Dynamic` or `Static` somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlHour" cssclass="select select-small" runat="server">  
  <asp:listitem value="0" Text="" selected="true"></asp:listitem>  
  <asp:listitem value="1">1</asp:listitem>  
  <asp:listitem value="2">2</asp:listitem>  
</asp:dropdownlist>  
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HourValidate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlHour" ErrorMessage="Please select an hour" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong thing. :) Try the new code I just added.

Answer (score -1):

how to set required field validator with `DropDownList`

suppose you are having this items in your dropdownlist..

```
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--","0"));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Kaushal","1"));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Naresh","2"));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Pankaj", "3"));
```

**Then -:** set the `requiredfieldvalidator`'s controltovalidate property to `DropDownlist1` and set the `InitialValue` property of the `requiredfieldvalidator` to `0` as this will be the value for
`--Select--` you can show above.

Answer (score -2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are using the wrong validator. By default, a dropdown always has a value, so making it required doesn't make sense. I think what you want to do is compare it, to make sure it's not the first choice. This page shows a quick demo of how to do that.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1188035.aspx/1

Comment: This also causes the same issue, which mentioned before, is that this validation does not pass in only Firefox.

Comment: You can add empty options to dropdown lists which result in a null or empty value.  Examples of this are "Choose..." or "Select..." with a value of empty.